# When we declare a static vector in C, is the pointer to this vector stored?

Tags: c, pointers, vector

I would like to know if

```
int v [10];
```

Allocates (besides 10*sizeof(int) bytes) also a pointer to integer to this vector.

Comment: Not explicitly. The pointer is obtained by the compiler from the array, where necessary, so it might be "stored" as part of a processor instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two conceptual levels on which to understand this question.

First, C is defined in terms of an abstract machine. In this model, `v` identifies an array of ten `int`. `v` is not a pointer; “v” is the identifier, and the thing it identifies, named `v`, is an array of ten `int`. There is no pointer. When `v` is used in source code in an expression other than for taking its size (with `sizeof`) or its address (with `&`), it is automatically converted to a pointer. This pointer is, in effect, manufactured as needed—it has not been (in the model described by the C standard) stored anywhere or loaded from anywhere. It is just made when needed.

Second, when C implementations use arrays, they have various ways of referring to memory. If the array is a static object (because it was defined outside of any function), it is typically placed in some location in a segment of memory reserved for static data. There are various ways that C implementations refer to this memory, including:

- The compiler puts information in the object file about which memory locations it wants to refer to. As the program is linked and loaded, the linker and the loader adjust this information and change the machine instructions as necessary so they refer to the final address of the object. This may result in instructions that contain the full absolute address of the object or instructions that refer to the object by how far it is from some register that contains a base address.
- When the program is loaded, the loader chooses where to put data in memory and sets a register to contain a base address for the data. When the compiler is compiling the program, it writes instructions that refer to static objects using offsets that indicate how far the objects are from this base address.

If the object is automatic instead of static (as when defined inside a function, without the `static` keyword), typical C implementations use memory on the stack. This method is similar to the base-register-and-offset method described above, but the base register is a special register called the stack pointer, which is adjusted as each function is called to point to memory reserved just for the use of that particular function call.

Whenever the base-register-and-offset method is used, the absolute address never exists in a way observed by the program. For example, an instruction may contain a location reference such as `38(sp)` (as described in assembly language), which means “38 bytes beyond where the stack pointer points.” The processor would take the contents of the stack pointer, add 38 to them, and fetch (if reading) the contents of that location from memory. In this case, the absolute address exists momentarily somewhere inside the processor where it does that addition of 38.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no additional pointer allocation.

Ten ints-worth of memory is allocated on the stack (if declared inside the function) or in the data segment (if declared globally). Although v conceptually contains the address of the beginning of this memory block, it doesn't need any additional storage for it, since v disappears when the code is compiled.

Comment: Thank you very much, so when in the code we do something like 
*(v+1) = x , the compiler transforms it in something like *(&v[0]+1)?

Comment: “Static heap” is not an appropriate term. Static objects are not usually maintained in a heap. Even the memory managed by the `malloc` family of routines is not generally a heap.

Comment: Precisely, which is why we can write '5[v]' instead of 'v[5]'. But it's not recommended :).

Comment: `v` does not “conceptually contain the address.” `v` is an identifier. The array is an object. `v` identifies the array. The compiler has whatever information it needs about the location of the object. `v` identifies it; it does not contain its address.

Comment: An array defined externally (outside any function) with `int v[10];` is generally not in the data segment. First, whether there is a data segment is an implementation detail, not part of the standard C model. Second, the data segment is generally used for non-zero initialized objects. Objects with default initialization may go into the BSS segment (in implementations that use it).

Answer (score 1):

Technically, when you declare the `v` array, you offset the memory stack with an address range appropriate to store 10 `ints`. You can see this if you use a compiler to generate the underlying assembly code of your c instructions. The assembly stores the address to those stack position

Using x86-64 gcc 9.3, I compiled this assembly with a slightly extended version of the example you gave.

```
int main(void){
    int v [10];
    v[0] = 0;
    v[1] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-48], 0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-44], 1
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Telling you all about what each instruction mean is beyond this answer but you can see how the 0 and 1 is pushed to the stack at an offset appropriate to the size of an int. The reason the compiler dont allocate exactly the minimum required space has to do with other optimization instructions belonging to compiler implementations.

Comment: Seeing the underlying assembly is an idea I didn't think of, thank you! Yeah, I see that no pointer v is stored there